# Broken upgrade 18.04 to 20.04 - can log into tty2 not Gnome desktop environment

Tags: boot, 18.04, 20.04, upgrade

PC is a desktop AMD64, 8GB RAM, 1TB hdd. Ubuntu 18.04.

Sudo apt-get **upgrade** when I only wanted to **update**, my bad. The upgrade then proceeded to **dist-upgrade** 18.04 to 20.04. Unfortunately this upgrade process was interrupted before it completed normally.

System now signs-on at boot saying ***Welcome to 20.04***, more messages, then stalls. At this point, **Alt-F2** prompt lets me log in with password, can see all files etc. **Alt-F1** is the frozen sign-in messages, tail here
`[ OK ] Started GNOME Display Manager.`
`[ OK ] Started Network Manager Script Dispatch Service.`
`[ OK ] Started Manage, Install and Generate Color profiles.`
`[ OK ] Created slice User Slice of gdm.`
       `Starting User Manager for UID 121 ...`
`[ OK ] Started Session c1 of user gdm.`
`[ OK ] Started User Manager for UID 121.`
`[ OK ] Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes ....pleted startup.ures....`

My question is, how can I either re-initiate/complete the upgrade, or repair the 20.04? As I'm hoping to resume use of mail, browsing and many other apps installed there.

Comment: Try `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: That worked well. I had to unlock something and used this [unlock guide](https://itsfoss.com/could-not-get-lock-error/). Also used --fix-missing.  Two problems with regular boot now, and can get to SU maintenance mode OK.  

1. **Failed to start GNOME Display manager"  

2. **Failed to start CUPS scheduler** keeps cycling through Stopped Started Listening 1 min 30s repeatedly. When **systemctl status cups.service** queried says OK OK.